# Write text within a path or polygon in SVG or Raphael.js

Tags: html, svg, geometry, raphael

I am using Raphael.js to create polygons, (or actually closed paths) over an image.  I want to put text inside the polygons.  Is there any way to create a text element and then adjust its size and position so that the whole thing will be within the bounds of a polygon?

Are there at least any algorithms that can give me good guesses that I could manually adjust?

Comment: How complex would these polygons be -- could you provide an example or two of the most extreme cases?

Comment: They can be arbitrarily complex.  They should all be closed polygons.  They'll generally have four or more sides.  They might be convex polygons, but an algorithm that will at least work for concave polygons would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I gave this some thought over the course of the day, and finally had the chance to throw together a little demo code.  It is *glaringly imperfect* in many ways but may form a good starting place, and does seem to work well with most of my randomly generated polygons.

**Part 1: Centering the text over the polygon**.  Using the bounding box proved wildly unsatisfactory, so instead of I devised a technique to average all of the points in a given path `container`:

```
            //  Determine the *weighted* center of this figure
            var segments = Raphael.parsePathString( container.attr( 'path' ) );
            var count = 0, sum_x = 0, sum_y = 0;
            for ( var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++ )
            {
                if ( segments[i][0] == 'L' || segments[i][0] == 'M' )
                {
                    count++;
                    sum_x += segments[i][1];
                    sum_y += segments[i][2];
                }
            }

            var cx = sum_x / count, cy = sum_y / count;
```

**Part 2: Collision detection**.  I needed a mechanism to check if a given object is inside the current shape.  Being lazy, I simply extended the Raphael element object prior to creating my canvas.

```
        Raphael.el.isObjectInside = function( obj )
        {
            var box = obj.getBBox();
            return this.isPointInside( box.x, box.y ) 
                        &&
                    this.isPointInside( box.x2, box.y )
                        &&
                    this.isPointInside( box.x, box.y2 )
                        &&
                    this.isPointInside( box.x2, box.y2 );
        }
```

**Part 3: Iterative sizing**.  Basically, we use the coordinates produced above and apply them to the generated label text.  We reduce the scale once each iteration until we go beneath a certain threshold, at which point MY code simply gives up (yours probably shouldn't):

```
            var s = 1.0;
            if ( ibox.width >= cbox.width * 0.7 )
            {
                s = ( cbox.width * 0.7 ) / ibox.width;
            }

            while ( s > 0.1 )
            {
                insert.attr( { transform: [ "S", s, s, ibox.x + ibox.width / 2, ibox.y + ibox.height / 2, "T", 
                if ( container.isObjectInside( insert ) )
                    return;
                s *= 0.65;
            }

            console.log("Warning: NOT a clean fit" );
```

And the result looks well for most of the purely random polygons I threw at it.  I'm sure it's far more computationally intensive than it needs to be.  My code is staged [here](http://voidblossom.com/tests/polygonDodger.php) -- just click on the polygon to generate a new one.

Happy coding.

Comment: This looks like a good starting point (if not an exact fit) for what I want to do with Raphael. Unfortunately, the link to your code is broken (the site spits out a 404 for that page). Is there any chance you can create a fiddle with your code?